# Multi-color text in one Gtk.Label

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I'm using a css file for theming my interface. So I have currently this:

```
    style_file = Gio.File.new_for_path('interface.css')
    style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    style_provider.load_from_file(style_file)

    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
        Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
        style_provider,
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
    )

    self.label = Gtk.Label()
    self.label.set_name('foobar_label')
    self.label.set_markup("<span color='blue'>foo </span>"
                          "<span color='green'>{} </span>"
                          "<span color='red'>"
                          "bar</span>".format(baz))
```

I want to get rid of set_markup call and use the css for style it. I really must create three separated labels just for color it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to style substrings of a `Gtk.Label` using CSS, though it does involve a bit of a workaround.

Here is one example written in Javascript: https://github.com/endlessm/eos-knowledge-lib/blob/d4c9666/js/app/utils.js#L170-L225

Basically it involves temporarily adding another style class to the widget's context to pick up the extra styles from your CSS, then translating that into Pango markup. You would call `format_ui_string()` when constructing your label and also whenever the style is updated ([`style-updated`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.signals.style_updated) signal.)